# Can we use the word "federated learning" for non-machine learning solutions?

Tags: machine-learning, federated-learning

My question is can we use "learning" when we don't employ deep learning or a ML model but simply "learning" from the data using basic statistics?

Answer (score 0):

While the term "federated learning" is specifically associated with machine learning techniques and training models in a decentralized manner, the concept of leveraging distributed data for collaborative learning can be applied beyond traditional machine learning scenarios. **The fundamental idea of federated learning, which involves training AI models without centralizing the data, can be conceptually extended to other domains where collaborative learning from distributed data is beneficial.**

For instance, federated learning principles can be applied to scenarios involving collaborative data analysis, where multiple parties contribute their data for joint analysis while maintaining data privacy and security. This could involve scenarios such as collaborative statistical analysis, where data from different sources is analyzed collectively while preserving the privacy and security of individual datasets.